# HASP service will not start

Tags: windows, windows-7, hasp

I have a client who's HASP driver will not start. When we go into services and attempt to start it manually it still will not start. It is set to start automatically. Additionally, and obviously, attempting to go to `http://localhost:1741` in their web browser does not work.

Does anyone know why the HASP driver would fail to start?

The version in question is from 02/12/2004 (back when it was still Aladdin) although I'm not sure of the actual version number. We're also talking about a Windows 7 (32-bit) PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem was that the HASP driver will not work sometimes if you access the PC through a remote desktop connection.

Answer (score 0):

You trying to use a very ancient version of the HASP driver. You need to get an actual version and try to install it. Official website with drivers located here: https://sentinelcustomer.safenet-inc.com/sentineldownloads/?s=&c=End+User&p=HASP4&o=Windows&t=all&l=all

If you will still get an error, then you need to check installation logs: C:\Windows\aksdrvsetup.log